# "ImportError: No module named _SHA256" when using PHP's exec() to call python script

Tags: php, python, import, exec

I have written a python script "thescript.py" that imports "SHA256.py", both of which are in the same directory "/thedirectory/include/".

In PHP I do:

```
chdir('/thedirectory/include/');
$result = exec('thescript.py argument1 2>&1');
```

Which gives me the result:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "thescript.py",
>   line 4, in ?
>       import SHA256   File "/thedirectory/include/SHA256.py", line 152, in ?
>       import _SHA256 ImportError: No module named _SHA25

The SHA256.py lines that cause this error are here:

```
try:
    import hashlib
    hashFactory = hashlib.sha256
except ImportError:
    #from Crypto.Hash import _SHA256
    import _SHA256  # <--- ERROR IS OCCURRING ON THIS LINE
    hashFactory = _SHA256
```

If I run this from the command line via SSH it runs fine. Why can't it import _SHA256?

To be honest I don't understand what the underscore before the package name is even doing.

Is the line `import _SHA256` in "SHA256.py" importing itself, or something?

Comment: Is `_SHA256` an actual python module? I can't find anything about it in google, and it's not in my python installation.

Comment: I just discovered that the problem is really that `import hashlib` is failing when I do exec() from PHP. But hashlib is found when I run the script from the shell. So I guess I need to add the hashlib path somehow.

Comment: _SHA256 is not the same as SHA256, it's a distinct module. The leading underscore has the connotation of internal/private, but apart from that the underscore is just another character. The semantics of this block of code is "we prefer to use the implementation in the hashlib module, but if that is not available in this environment, we can fall back to the _SHA256 module." In your case, neither one is available.

Answer (score 1):

This is because path may be different when you are executing via exec.

Check your path while executing python via exec command in php

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP was running the wrong version of python.

It was actually the `import hashlib` that was failing, though I failed to notice this because it was in the `try` block, thus not raising an error on that line.